# Disable drag event in input type range

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input, reactstrap

> I have an input type "range" element in a React Component (using
>   reactstrap Input) to manage percentage, so i have set a minimum of 0
>   and a maximum of 100, using a step of 25. My problem is that I'd like
>   to disable the drag event and use only the click event. Is there any
>   chance of doing it? I'm not using and I'm not gonna use jQuery.

Thank you!

Edit: 
I manage to solve it. Basically I added an "onMouseMove" event with "e.preventDefault()" and now the slider doesn't move on dragging but only on clicking.